# form_for : how to post user_id and topic_id in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm using a form to add an post, and I need to send the id of the current user along with the entry parameters. Here is my form code:

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, :value => topic.id %>
        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "yorumunuzu girin..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and my posts_controller :

```
def new
        @topic= Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
    end

    def show
    @post= Post.find(params[:id])
    @topic= @post.topic
  end 

    def create
        @topic= Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])
        @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
            redirect_to topic_path(topic)
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end
```

I use partials so i use these code in the topic_controller.rb

```
  def show      
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
        @posts = @topic.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
        @post = @topic.posts.build if signed_in?
  end
```

I nested my resources :

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

resources :topics , only: [:show, :create, :destroy] do
resources :posts, only: [:create, :show, :new]
end
```

. when i post a comment, error log is :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"y0wzskqK9LfXSPIYW4EmqRii1Tg7bD1CG0kno+gcagQ=",
 "post"=>{"user_id"=>"1",
 "content"=>"yeni yorum"},
 "commit"=>"Gönder",
 "topic_id"=>"3"}
```

So It does not post the `topic_id`.
In the topic show page I want to show the topic, the posts belonging to it and a post form. And when a user posts a comment I want it redirect to same page.So my `redirect_to topic_path(topic)`is correct or wrong?.  Thank for reading .

EDIT 1: I tried the below solutions . I changed

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, :value => @post.topic.id %>
```

Now the error code changed

```
 undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"y0wzskqK9LfXSPIYW4EmqRii1Tg7bD1CG0kno+gcagQ=",
 "post"=>{"user_id"=>"1",
 "topic_id"=>"3",
 "content"=>"yorum"},
 "commit"=>"Gönder",
 "topic_id"=>"3"}
```

I must edit my new action . My mind is stuck but I wont give up.

Comment: i don't understand your problem, but shouldn't it be ```redirect_to topic_path(@topic)``` with an ```@``` you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have nested routes (posts under topics) and you build your form with `<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| ... %>` you should have `topic_id` already accessible from your controller in:

```
params[:topic_id]
```

(thanks to the routing)

However you should not directly assign `topic_id` to post, but instead assign topic instance.

```
# wrong (security flaw)
@post.topic_id = params[:topic_id]

# correct
@post.topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
```

That way you can make necessary checks on the topic - make sure that it exists, user is allowed to use it, etc. Otherwise user can easily send you any value he wants.

[edit]

For the same reason you don't want to post `user_id` in your form, because it can be manually altered by malicious user even if it's hidden field. Instead assign user to post in controller.

```
@post.user = current_user
```

Comment: def create @topic= Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post]).So how must i rebuild this line is this correct?

Comment: You need to find topic by `params[:topid_id]`, not `params[:id]`. You can also add `@post.user = current_user` and then `@post.save`

Comment: I made it .. this is the posts_controller with correct redirect_to

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an hidden form field wich submits the value's after you submit it make sure you add the hash key values to your update_attribute or create method.

NOTE:
with hidden fields you need to set the value by adding the actual value key as in:

```
f.hidden_field, :topic_id, :value => post.topic.id
```

then in your update or create function you want to add the submitted param value as in:

```
n = Comment.new
n.topic_id = params[:form_key][:topic_id].to_i
```

have fun

Comment: In my new action i use params[:post] .. Shall i seperate it?

Comment: You could do that although you need to be aware of a vulrenability called Mass Assignment just make sure protected credentials aren't passed through the submit

Comment: I can't understand why it only posts user_id. It should send the topic_id also because i have a line :<%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, :value => topic.id %>

Comment: I suggest trying to specificly assign the key value of topic_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for my problem:

posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy


    def new
   @topic= Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
   @post = @topic.posts.build
  end

    def create
        @topic= Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
        @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
        @post.user = current_user
        @post.topic_id = @topic.id

        if @post.save
            flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
            redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end
  private

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @post.nil?
    end
end
```

And _post_form.html.erb

```
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">


        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "yorumunuzu girin..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and routes table routes.rb :

```
resources :topics , only: [:show, :create, :destroy] do
    resources :posts, only: [:create, :new]
    end
```

I can write a post and it shows in the topics page . I have spent two days for this problem .Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Just a quick note: you don't need `@post.topic_id = @topic.id` line in `create` method as `topic_id` is already set when you `build` the object